# How do I architect a database with many to many relationships between all classes?

Tags: database-design

I have about 6 classes. Each has a many to many relationship with the others. I thought about using a tree structure, but that is hierarchical...and their relationship is not hierarchical.

Comment: What information modeling & database design textbook are you following? Where are you stuck following its process? If you aren't following one, why are you asking a question? Also your description of your "tree structure" is not clear, nor in what sense it is "hierarchical" or bad. PS Tables represent business relation(ship)s/associations in which values and/or enties identified by values participate. So determine what those are and give each one a table. Of course, you need to follow a design method to get good designs.

Answer (score 0):

A soultion is to add an extra table foreach many to many relationship. The only values it holds are references to the PKs of the related tables. These 2 FKs then build the PK for the m:m relational table itself. For example:

player table & tournament table - a player can participate in many tournaments, one tournament can have many players competing in.

m:m -> PlayerId  +++ TournamentId   ; these 2 are everything in the table and they shall be the PK and be unique. So you dont have redundant data in it.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid creating all of those many to many tables. I thought there might be an easier way.

Comment: Just creating these junction tables is the 'easiest way' I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You use what is called a junction table for each many to many relationship. So for instance suppose you have Users and Projects as two of your tables that have a many to many relationship. You build a table called UserProjects with UserId and ProjectId and nothing else. then you create the primary key on those two fields. Then you create a foreign key from UserId - the user table and on ProjectId to the Project table.